# Print JSON with two double-quotes

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to print the list using two double-quotes

```
>>> l = ["ABC", "123"]
>>> print(l)
['ABC', '123']
>>> print(json.dumps(l))
["ABC", "123"]
>>> print('"{}"'.format(l))
"['ABC', '123']"
```

I have tried to use json.dumps and format like above code. I need to print the list like this:

```
"[""ABC"", ""123""]"
```

Any idea to print the list following this format?

Thanks!

Comment: `json.dumps(l).replace('"', '""')`?

Comment: @cs95 That ends up `'["ABC", "123"]'`, the single quotes outside are still present

Comment: thank you! I can get what i want using your code --  print('"{}"'.format(json.dumps(l).replace('"', '""')))

Comment: @cs95, please add this as answer , so that others will find it helpful

Comment: @VenkataramanR Feel free to do so.

Comment: @cs95, I have done it. ideally, you should get the credit

Comment: I have made it as community wiki.

Comment: @cs95, Great compilation. thanks. I have not worked on pandas. But, in future, If I work, it will be a great source of reference. thanks for putting effort to compile them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting answer of @cs95, for others to be helpful.

```
json.dumps(l).replace('"', '""')
```